# Django rest serializer Breaks when data exists

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-users

I have this model:

```
class MyModel(User):
    #others fields
```

and this serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'some_field')
```

I get data from ajax to make a login and I handle it like this:

```
serializer = MySerializer(data=request.DATA)
print(serializer.is_valid())
```

**The problem:** When I send any data my serializer works but when my `username field`, which must be unique as `User model` describe,  matches with one at the database the serialize become invalid, so `serializer.is_valid()` return **False**

Why? can not I create a serialize object with data which must be unique and already exists in the database?

Comment: its trying to create a new model instance of `MyModel`, but it cant do so validly because the username already exists. You should be using [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) instead to subclass user.

Comment: you should also make sure the lookup field on your serializer is set to `username`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using `ModelSerializer` which automatically generates validators for your serializer. You should use normal `Serializer` class instead.

[Validation in REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/)