# "<Model> with this <field> already exist" on PUT call - Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm doing a HTTP PUT call to update the data of an object with a **nested relationship**, and I'm met by the following error:

> HTTP 400 Bad Request
>
> "AttributeChoice with this slug already exists."

The reason why this is confusing is because I'm doing a `HTTP PUT` call and I expect it to treat it as an `UPDATE` and not a `CREATE`.

My Models look like this:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text_input  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class AttributeChoice(models.Model):
    attribute   = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
    value       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

My Serializers look like this:

```
class AttributeChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AttributeChoice
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': False}}

class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attributechoice_set = AttributeChoiceSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'text_input', 'slug', 'attributechoice_set')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        choice_data = validated_data.pop('attributechoice_set') 
        for choice in choice_data:
        
            # If id is within the call, then update the object with matching id
            if 'id' in choice:
                try:
                    choice_obj = AttributeChoice.objects.get(pk=choice['id'])
                    choice_obj.value = choice['value']
                    choice_obj.slug = choice['slug']
                    choice_obj.attribute = instance
                # If ID is not found, then create a new object
                except AttributeChoice.DoesNotExist:
                    choice_obj = AttributeChoice(**choice)
            # If no ID within the call, create a new object.
            else:
                choice_obj = AttributeChoice(**choice)

            choice_obj.save()

        return instance
```

**Debug:**
Even if I remove the `update()` function, I still get the same error. I believe the error is reported from when `.is_valid()` is called in the ViewSet. So it's not the `update()` that causes it.

Also, if I remove `attributechoice_set = AttributeChoiceSerializer(many=True)` and just include the `attributechoice_set` in the `fields = ()`, the error disappears, but I need that line for the rest of the code to work.

Comment: Why do you set `read_only=False` for the `AttributeChoiceSerializer`?

Comment: You mean for the id? I need to have the id in `validated_data` and I need it to be writeable to be able to keep it in the `update()`. I don't see what it has to do with the Slug error though.

Comment: You don't need the id, you can also use the `slug` to get the object. Maybe the validate checks if an objects with this id and slug can be created.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Even through you're doing an update, it doesn't mean the nested data will just be updated.

You're simply saying that you want to update the top most object.

In some cases, you'll be removing or creating new nested objects while updating the top most one.

Therefore DRF considers by default that nested objects are for creation. You can work around this by explicitly removing the unique constraint on the nested serializer:

```
class AttributeChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AttributeChoice
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': False},
            'slug': {'validators': []},
        }
```

Comment: but what if we want to keep the validation ?

Comment: By the time of writing that answer, I don't think there was other validators. You can print the serializer, look at the existing validators on that field and pick those you want to keep.

Comment: Also note that the base validation is performed outside validators.

Comment: thanks. seems it has not changed yet. I have a deep relationship which I wanted to update. seems django don't have option for it.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has already developed a handy `UniqueFieldsMixin` for [solving the problem](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested#validation-problem-for-nested-serializers-with-unique-fields-on-update):

```
pip install drf-writable-nested
```

now:

```
from drf_writable_nested import UniqueFieldsMixin

class User(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class UserSerializer(UniqueFieldsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the validators.

Like:

[Django rest serializer Breaks when data exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942406/django-rest-serializer-breaks-when-data-exists)

As my solution, I mark this nested field to `read_only=True`,
And do my own update, create function to access `self.initial_data` to handle myself.