# Update ManytoMany relationship in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my django application I have a ManytoMany relationship between `Orders` and `Packages`. An order can have multiple packages. I want to know about the update and create methods

Models.py

```
class Package(models.Model):

    prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    unit_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Orders(models.Model):

    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    package = models.ManyToManyField(Package)
    is_cod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializers.py

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = "__all__"

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    package = PackageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"
```

Views.py

```
class OrdersCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Is that sufficient to handle the related data? I am trying to understand `ManytoMany` relationship both in Django as well as DRF so please explain if I need to change the Models or views in anyway

Update:

I have updated my serializer as well as view in order to create `manytomany` related objectslike this:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    package = PackageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        package_data = validated_data.pop('package')
        pkgs = []
        order = Orders.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for i in package_data:
            try:
                p = Package.objects.create(**i)
                pkgs.append(p)
            except:
                pass
        order.package.set(pkgs)
        return order
```

Views.py

```
class OrdersCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

However I am still unclear about overriding the `update` method of `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`. Also, Is the above method is the right method to store `M2M` related objects ?

Please help with the update part of the serializer, I understand that I have to pass the query in the serializer

Comment: Tip: You don't have to override the **`post(....)`**, DRF will handle it for you :)

Comment: DRF works seamlessly with FK and M2M relationship *if you are sending `PK` values* and it is the default behavior. In your case, you need to override the **`create()`** and **`update()`** methods of serializer

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  I don't have to create post function ? Post is defaultly handled by the `serializers` ? And if it does, wouldn't it create the `object` so why do I have to override the create function?

Comment: here the `post()` method creates a new object in DB (ideally) which is handled internally by **`generics.CreateAPIView`**, not by Serializer.

Comment: thanks for the info, could you kindly also help me with overriding the create function

Comment: I hope you will find plenty of resources on the internet related to that, use search word something like *"writable nested serializer DRF"*.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have updated the question, I am able to create the m2m relationship.. please have a look

Comment: can you add the sample create payload as well as the update payload?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have update the `create` but I am not sure how to handle the `update` part

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Working codebase

```
#serializers.py
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = "__all__"


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    package = PackageSerializer(many=True)

    def get_or_create_packages(self, packages):
        package_ids = []
        for package in packages:
            package_instance, created = Package.objects.get_or_create(pk=package.get('id'), defaults=package)
            package_ids.append(package_instance.pk)
        return package_ids

    def create_or_update_packages(self, packages):
        package_ids = []
        for package in packages:
            package_instance, created = Package.objects.update_or_create(pk=package.get('id'), defaults=package)
            package_ids.append(package_instance.pk)
        return package_ids

    def create(self, validated_data):
        package = validated_data.pop('package', [])
        order = Orders.objects.create(**validated_data)
        order.package.set(self.get_or_create_packages(package))
        return order

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        package = validated_data.pop('package', [])
        instance.package.set(self.create_or_update_packages(package))
        fields = ['order_id', 'is_cod']
        for field in fields:
            try:
                setattr(instance, field, validated_data[field])
            except KeyError:  # validated_data may not contain all fields during HTTP PATCH
                pass
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"

#views.py
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    queryset = Orders.objects.all()
```

Register this view with the help of [**`DefaultRouter`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) as,

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'order', OrderViewSet, basename='order')
urlpatterns = [

              ] + router.urls
```

Thus you will get basic CRUD end-points as described in that table (see the `DefaultRouter` ref).

Let your *order list* end-point be `/foo-bar/order/`

1. HTTP POST to `/foo-bar/order/` to create a new instance
2. HTTP PUT or HTTP PATCH to `/foo-bar/order/<ORDER_PK>/` to update the content

#### Note

In this case, you should pass the `id` value of package if you wish to map an existing *package* relation with the `Order`

#### References

1. [DRF `ModelVieSet`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)
2. [Django `get_or_create(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create)
3. [Django `create_or_update(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create)
4. [Django *M2M* `set(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set)
5. [DRF `DefaultRouter`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter)

---

### UPDATE-1

You can wire-up the view like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/order/', OrderViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'})),  # create new Order instance
    path('foo/order/<int:pk>/', OrderViewSet.as_view({'patch': 'partial_update'})),  # update Order instance

]
```

**Note:** This supports only `HTTP POST` and `HTTP PATCH`

Comment: How would I pass the `pk` in the Views such that I only update the selected Record?

Comment: @RahulSharma  I have updated the answer. Please do check it

Comment: The code is very well written and very helpful but I am trying to learn the basics thus I would Like to do it with URL as `foo-bar/<int:pk>/, OrdersUpdate.as_view())`. Please show me that way, Also if you could simplify the Update, it'd be very much helpful

Comment: Regarding the URL pattern, check `UPDATE-1` section. Regarding the `update(...)` method breakdown, I don't this it's a complicated piece of code. Go through it, everything in the code snippet is already in Python (so in Django) and you will get easy references to all those methods/functions/classes.

Comment: Thanks :) I have some stupid questions so I'll ask.. Would the `Update` will handle if I delete the `Packages` ?  And, why did you write `package_instance, created ` but appended only `package_instance.pk` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *delete*? Deleting a `Package` entry from Database? Have you check the doc of `update_or_create(...)` and `get_or_create(...)`?

Comment: By delete I meant If I am editing the `Order` and delete a particular `Package` object. For e.g. let's say `Order` object has two `packages` i.e. Foo and Bar and I delete Bar from frontend and call the request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213351/discussion-between-arakkal-abu-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: This doesn't work, serializer tries to validate the data before hand (django 3+)

Comment: You may have problem with unique field in nested model. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/36334825/3139228 in addition to this answer.