# Django Rest-Framework: how to add/remove entries in ManyToMany relations?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've just gone through the [Django-Rest-Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) (DRF) tutorial and tried to adapt it to a simple photos app I am working on with models `Album` and `Photo` in a M-2-M relationship: an album can have many photos, and a photo can be in many albums. The db has tables `myapp_album`, `myapp_photo` and `myapp_album_photos`, as you'd expect.

But what I want is to be able to create albums and photos **independent** of each other and **then** to create the relations between them. I can do that easily in the shell with the `photo.add(album)`, etc. but it's not clear to me how to do this via the generated DRF routes.

The problem is that using the terse DRF abstractions that I gleaned from the tutorial (using ModelSerializer, viewsets, etc.), I only end up with routes to `/albums` and `/photos`, and it's not clear to me how to create a route (or how otherwise) to associate *existing* photos with *existing* albums.

Could someone please help clarify the situation? Thanks

```
### models.py
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    caption = models.TextField(blank=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    description = models.TextField()
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo)


### serializers.py
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description']

class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'caption', 'datetime', 'filename']

### views.py
class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
```

Comment: Have you tried updating `to_representation` of `PhotoSerializer` ? also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61537923/update-manytomany-relationship-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to construct this functionality by hand.

1. You can create an `AlbumPhoto` model that represents a relationship between a photo and an album. Then, you can use the default serializers and view sets for this model. By setting the `through` and `through_fields` settings of `ManyToManyField`, you should be able to use the new model without changing your existing model code.

   ```python
   ### models.py
   class Photo(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
       caption = models.TextField(blank=True)
       datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
       filename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

   class AlbumPhoto(models.Model):
       album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       # add any extra information about this relationship
       # such as the order number of this photo in the album

   class Album(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
       description = models.TextField()
       photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo,
           through='AlbumPhoto',
           through_fields=('album', 'photo'))

   ### serializers.py
   class AlbumPhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = AlbumPhoto
           fields = ['id', 'album', 'photo']

   ### views.py
   class AlbumPhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = AlbumPhoto.objects.all()
       serializer_class = AlbumPhotoSerializer
   ```

   To add a photo to an album, issue this `POST` request to `/albumphoto/`:

   ```json
   {
       "album": 1,
       "photo": 1
   }
   ```

   This example works with Django 4.0.1, Django REST Framework 3.13.1, and Python 3.9.6.
2. You can use a [writable nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), overriding the `create()` and `update()` methods to accept a list of related items when updating your photos or albums list. Here's an untested `update()` function that lets you add a list of `Album` IDs to a `Photo` model:

   ```python
   class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       class Meta:
           model = Photo
           fields = ['id', 'title', 'caption', 'datetime', 'filename', 'albums']

       def update(self, instance, validated_data):
           # Use pop() to remove the many-to-many fields
           # for custom processing.
           albums = validated_data.pop('albums')
           # Add each album to the photo instance.
           for album in albums:
               instance.albums.add(album)
           # Let the base class update() function
           # do the rest of the work.
           return super().update(instance, validated_data)
   ```
3. You can create your own views for adding relationships between existing `Photo` and `Album` objects. If you're going to go to all the trouble, I think option 1 is better.

Comment: Thanks very much for this -- very helpful. I am still researching the options and will let you know what I end up doing.